# Telegram Бот не обрабатывает второй Handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Бот обрабатывает 1-ый Handler на сообщение, но на второй просто не реагирует, в консоли логов никаких нет, подскажите, в чём проблема? код: https://pastebin.com/sveT081h

Comment: Не первый вопрос про телеграмных ботов, а все также высвечивает телеграмный токен, который должен храниться в условиях строгой тайны, а то спамеры набегут от чужого имени постить. А код так работает потому, что так устроен telebot, когда он нашел подходящий `message_handler`, он его выполняет и на этом успокаивается. Если порыться в исходниках, можно в этом убедиться https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/b1e5d008216837a0d966197a0388580ad590f4e8/telebot/__init__.py#L1792.

Comment: Токен высвечиваю, потому что бот тестовый, следовательно и спамить ему некому. Если он устроен так, то как решить проблему? Делать в одном handler'e несколько функций?

Comment: Ну ладно, не знал как это устроено, больше не стану удивляться. По поводу решения задачи, похоже, что так и есть. Для модульности можно разбить на несколько собственных функций, а потом вызывать их в одной через `if` и эту одну задекорировать `message_handler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код так работает потому, что так устроен telebot, когда он нашел первый подходящий message_handler, он его выполняет и на этом успокаивается. Если порыться в исходниках, можно в этом [убедиться](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/b1e5d008216837a0d966197a0388580ad590f4e8/telebot/__init__.py#L1792).

Можно все решить двумя способами. Объединить обработчики в один и в `if` проверять содержание сообщение и исполнять нужный код. Но можно и по-другому.

В readme в репозитории на гитхабе, который скинул - там [упомянуто](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/tree/b1e5d008216837a0d966197a0388580ad590f4e8#message-handlers), что декоратор `message_handler` может принимать параметр `func, туда передается функция, принимающая аргумент message, а возвращающая True/False.

В таком случае можно проверять условие срабатывания прямо в декораторе.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'], func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == "проверить подписку")
def check(message):
    for chri in statuses:
        # ...

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'], func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == "получить ключ")
def key(message):
    # ...
```

Должно сработать.